# how to send parameters with file in android

Tags: java, php, android

I am uploading image in android. Currently my code only uploads file but I also want to send some parameter. I am trying following

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
        conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        //Sending data
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"paramName\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(globalUID);
```

and on the server side I am using php. here is how I am trying to get that parameter

```
$param = $_POST["paramName"];
target_path1 = "./places_photos/" . $param;
```

But my current code does upload file but it does not send parameters. How can I send parameters and how can I get them on server side?

**Update**

Currently, the image is saved in `places_photos` directory which is mentioned in `$target_path1` variable. What I want is to save that image in user's directory and that directory is named as user id. But unfortunately I am not getting userid on server side. How can I send userid to server along with file?

Answer (score 0):

There should be another lineEnd added after this:

```
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"paramName\"" + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(globalUID);
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd); <-- add this
```

Also make sure you add the end of the multipart boundary (the line that starts with '--') In your case, add this:

```
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
```

Comment: Can you use a tool like Firebug, or Wireshark, and trace what is the form post being sent to the server? The multi-part/form-data is very finicky about new lines and boundary being 100% correct.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to "make" the php know your file name??
if your answer is yes, so you can make some changes on your code.

(i assume you have created a buffer of maximum size and read file and write it into form)

first change
you don't need this to send paramName:

```
//Sending data
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"paramName\"" + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(globalUID);
```

just do this:

```
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
```

and in your php, change your code:

```
$param = $_POST["paramName"];
```

to

```
$param = basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
```

you can check [this](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/03/29/uploading-audio-video-or-image-files-from-android-to-server/) article

Comment: I want to send parameter to the server. My php already know the filename of the file.

Comment: if you just want to send parameter to the server you can execute a HTTP POST Request with HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

Set a cookie with userid in it. On server you can retrieve the cookie and check userid. (Though note that this is not secure and neither passsing userid parameter)

Comment: What you mention that is one option but this app requirement is to send parameter to the server with file upload. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit confusing, double check your variables... for instance your `target_path1` doesn't have a $ in front, check to see whether any of the other sever variables return any valid output.

If all fails however, you can rename the file being uploaded - including the parameters in the file name and renaming it at the server side again after extracting the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

this is very simple ...100% working solution

use UTF-8 to send parameter in url. add this line

```
 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL("http://your fileaddress.php***?yourphpsideparametername="+URLEncoder.encode(yourperameter, "UTF-8")***  );
```

then second add this line in connection request

```
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               ***conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF=8");***
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
```

add this line on php code

```
    $yourperameter =$_GET['yourparameter'];
    $file_path = "doc/".$yourperameter."/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    $title =$_FILES['title'];
    //$descr=$file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['desc']);

     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
```